# I want a button to trigger an action in a different view

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

So I have an app in Xcode that has a main view controller and an settings view controller. I want to have a segmented view in the settings view that triggers actions on the main view. The settings view controller is connected to its own class "settingsviewcontroller.h" and the view controller is connected to its own class "viewcontroller.h". So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to define a protocol:

**SettingsDelegate.h**:

```
@protocol SettingsDelegate
- (void)settingsUpdated:(NSDictionary *)newSettings
@end
```

Include this header in both of your view controllers. Have viewController conform to this protocol. Establish a weak reference from settings controller to viewcontroller, e.g.

**SettingsViewController.m**:

```
@interface SettingsViewController ()
@property (readwrite, weak) id<SettingsDelegate> settingsDelegate;
@end
```

When settingscontroller is instantiated, set `self.settingsDelegate` to the viewcontroller. Assuming you create the settingscontroller from the viewcontroller, it would be something like this:

**viewController.m**:

```
SettingsController *settingsController = [[SettingsController alloc] init];
settingsController.settingsDelegate = self;
// present the settingsController
```

In settings controller, when the settings are updated:

```
if (self.settingsDelegate) {
    NSDictionary *newSettings = ...; // set this value
    [self.settingsDelegate settingsUpdated:newSettings];
}
```

For more details, see Apple's **Working with Protocols**: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: I do not have a settings delegate .h though. What is that. Do I have to make something like a second app delegate.h?

Comment: Nope, you just need to create a new .h file without a corresponding .m file. All you would need in the new .h file is those three lines under **SettingsDelegate.h**.

Comment: I can create a sample Xcode project for you if you want.

Comment: So basically just create a new class but just make a new .h file? like how do I connect it to the settingsviewcontroller.h?

Comment: To create the new header file in Xcode, File > New... > File, then under iOS choose C and C++, and select Header File. This gives you just a .h file; there's no .m file in this case. Then save that as SettingsDelegate.h. In your two view controller .m files, add `#import "SettingsDelegate.h"`

Comment: Ok, I did not know about that, thanks, So after I do all of this how will I connect the segmented view controller to the action, will the action show up in the connections view (the little arrow in story boards) or do I have to do something else?

Comment: I typically make that connection in code, as in my sample code above. Does that work for you?

Comment: Will the connection show up in the story board though?

Comment: Ah I am not a storyboard user so I am not sure. I would assume you can make a connection for the settingsDelegate property there, but I don't know the answer of connecting the button action. You can search for "storyboard protocol" questions; I bet this has come up before.

Comment: Or would it work in the files owner. If it would work in the files owner it would work in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

*By the way I am not sure if this is right at all

The first way:

Try doing the -(IBAction)... connection. I know they are different views, but maybe you can still do the connection from different responders anyway.

The second way:

Try importing the .h/.m files so that you can access different variables etc... from the other class

Comment: I have tried both of these things. The first one does not work at all and it does not make sense that it would. The second one makes sense but after I did it nothing happened. I think you have to do that and then do something else but I do not know what

Comment: What is the action that you want the button to trigger?

Comment: One side of the segmented view controller is mph and the other side is kmh and when its on mph the labels in the view controller say mph and the formula to change the output is changed to make the output mph and km does the same thing but for kmh.